# How to create PFObject of existing on Parse object when offline

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using CoreData as main DB for the app and Parse local DB (pin) only for the objects that I can't send to Parse: create new or update old, because of Internet problem. **Question** is - if I want to update object in Parse I'm starting query to get this object, when got - update some data, and save again. But what if I'm trying update PFObject offline?
  How to create PFObject that will update the same object in Parse when Internet will? I'm using this:

```
 PFObject *parseObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MyClass"];

 if ([self isLocalID:[managObj valueForKey:@"id"]]) {
         parseObj.objectId = [managObj valueForKey:@"id"];
 }
```

And it's works well (online or offline it sending to Parse or pinned), but time to time I get this error: `Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the OfflineStore.` on row `parseObj.objectId = [managObj valueForKey:@"id"];` I assumed that reason for this error - that Parse local datastore already has an object with objectId that I trying to set, but before creating new PFObject I synchronously query from local datastore:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:updateObj.entity.name];
        [query fromLocalDatastore];
        [query whereKey:@"localID" containedIn:arrObjsLocalIDs];

        NSArray *objects =  [query findObjects];
        if (objects.count > 0) {
           // Send this array to Parse
        }
        else {
          // Created PFObjects
        }
```

When I'm using

```
  parseObj = [PFObject  objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"MyClass" 
objectId:[managObj valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

[object doesn't pinned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771560/pfobjects-created-with-objectwithoutdatawithclassname-doesnt-pin)

I'm struggling with this for the couple of days, what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I think I found a problem. I saved a reference to PFObject before sending to Parse (in case if app got killed I pinned it), and didn't nil it after.